# MYSQL SELECT statement failing within an UPDATE, within a LOOP

Tags: mysql, loops, select, insert-update

I am writing a stored procedure to update a company calendar. The calendar data is stored within a MYSQL table. The stored procedure is an insert function which should force all calendar events between two dates to be shifted to the next available business day. Type 1 denotes a day on the calendar. Type 2 denotes an event on the calendar.

The calendar recognizes a business day through the Moves column. A day with Moves(more than 0) is a business day on the calendar.

When I run this query by itself, it returns the expected information:

```
SELECT `Date`, Moves FROM tblschedules WHERE Type = 1;
```

It gives me the number of Moves for each day. However, when I try and update the table, the update does nothing, because the Moves column returns as NULL. Here is the query for the update:

```
    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
    UPDATE tblschedules tb1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT `Date`, Moves FROM tblschedules WHERE Type = 1) tb2 
    ON tb2.Date = tb1.Date
    SET tb1.Date = tb1.Date + Interval 1 Day
    WHERE tb1.Type = 2 AND tb1.Date >= ddate AND tb1.Date < opendate AND tb2.Moves = 0;
```

So, to debug, I began putting select statements within my stored procedure, and found that the initial query is not returning the `Moves` column, but instead returns null values as Moves. So that tb2 is returning every Date properly, but is not retrieving the Moves values properly.

Here is the larger block of code. The intloop, ddate and opendate are all functioning properly.

```
looplabel: Loop

    /* Select Statements for Debug Purposes*/
    
    SELECT opendate;
    SELECT ddate;
    SELECT intloop;

    SELECT `Date`, Moves FROM tblschedules WHERE Type = 1;

    SELECT * FROM tblschedules tb1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT `Date`, Moves FROM tblschedules WHERE Type = 1) tb2 
    ON tb2.Date = tb1.Date
    WHERE tb1.Type = 2 AND tb1.Date >= ddate AND tb1.Date < opendate;
  
    /* End of Select Statements for Debug Purposes*/
    
    IF IFNULL(intloop,0) = 0 THEN 
        LEAVE looplabel;
    END IF;   
    
    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
    UPDATE tblschedules tb1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT `Date`, Moves FROM tblschedules WHERE Type = 1) tb2 
    ON tb2.Date = tb1.Date
    SET tb1.Date = tb1.Date + Interval 1 Day
    WHERE tb1.Type = 2 AND tb1.Date >= ddate AND tb1.Date < opendate AND tb2.Moves = 0;
    SET intloop = intloop - 1;
END LOOP;
```

I am not sure why the table returns the Moves properly outside of the stored procedure, but not inside of the stored procedure. I am wondering if it might have something to do with uncommitted changes/table locking. Its probably something basic and stupid I am missing. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't see any way that `tb2.Moves` could be `NULL` unless you actually have some null values in the table.

Comment: Can you replicate the problem at sqlfiddle.com or db-fiddle.com?

Comment: What is the reason in subquery usage? ```UPDATE tblschedules tb1 INNER JOIN tblschedules tb2 ON tb2.Date = tb1.Date SET tb1.Date = tb1.Date + Interval 1 Day WHERE tb2.Type = 1 AND tb1.Type = 2 AND tb1.Date >= ddate AND tb1.Date < opendate AND tb2.Moves = 0;```. And what is the reason to perform this UPDATE more than once? *`SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;`* Set this once before loop and restore after it.

Comment: The purpose of the query is to check and see if each event is occurring on a business day(a day where moves > 0). If an event is scheduled for a non business day(a day with 0 moves) it is to be moved to the next day. This is looped through several times because the next calendar day might also be a non-business day.

Comment: *This is looped through several times because the next calendar day might also be a non-business day.* There is no any "loop by the calendar days" in your code.

Comment: Before this block of code, intloop is set to the number of calendar days between ddate(starting date) and the first empty businessday(opendate). So the code would run at least as many times as was needed. This may be inefficient as typically, from common use, the loop might iterate 7 times when only 3 times are necessary. At any rate, the iterations are working properly. I can tell that from my SELECT statements as a debugger. But what I cannot understand is why tb2.Moves is returning NULL.

Comment: I never did find out what was wrong here, but I worked around the problem by creating a temporary table and then joining the temporary table during the update. Thank you for the advice. I was unable to create stored procedures through sqlfiddle.com.